# How to get a list of record added after september

Tags: mysql

I'm writing a stored proc to retrieve all records added after the September 2023. Similarly as the year/month rolls to September 2024, it should automatically retrieve records added after Sep 2024.

I used condition

```
creation date >= CONCAT(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()),'-11-01');
```

However the issue with the above query is that it will automatically fetch records added after September 2024 when the year/month rolls into Jan 2024.

Can you please suggest how to fix this.

Comment: Add one more condition - date less or equal to XXXX-12-31, PS. September is `09`, not `11`... Alternatively - check that the year is equal to one of current date and month is between 9 and 12.

Comment: ??you want sep-dec only

Comment: September to September fiscal year

Comment: Just deduct 9 months from current day before taking year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This conditional query will help:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE creation_date >= 
  CASE 
    WHEN MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) >= 9 THEN DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%Y-09-01')
    ELSE DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 YEAR, '%Y-09-01')
  END;
```